# "Images are not visible" updates to questions and answers

Tags: discussion

User Sathya is editing/revising a lot of questions and answers with no apparent change. These are coming into the Suggested Edit review queue and I'm not entirely sure how to deal with them. They are commented with "images not visible", yet to me that doesn't appear to have been the case.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/4713/sathya?tab=activity&sort=revisions

I can't make out whether he's trying to game the badge system or i'm missing something from the update comment/pre-post views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like @Sathya is having a problem with spaces in the `alt` text for the image - here is the diff in the markdown:

[image]

Seems fairly legit, I think.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor